# How to insert record with ajax in modal Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

You want to add a product to a list through a modal window twitter bootstrap, in the window you are asked to add the name and the quantity.

[image: Modal]
my button that calls the modal:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myDesayuno" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Desayunos <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> </a>        @:&nbsp;
```

my modal and its call script:

```
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myDesayuno" @*tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"*@>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Agregar Desayuno</h3>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <form id="myForm" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Kn_CodigoProducto, "Desayuno", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.DropDownList("Kn_CodigoProducto", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Kn_CodigoProducto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.d_Cantidad, "Cantidad", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.d_Cantidad, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Agregar Cantidad" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.d_Cantidad, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    <input type="reset" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" value="Agregar Desayuno" />
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->

  @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")    
    <script>
           function launch_modal(id) {
         // Hide all modals using class if required.
         $('.modal').modal('hide');
         $('#'+id).modal('show');
             }
        </script>

}
```

It is wanted that when the user enters name and quantity of product, this click in "Add Product" and the products are loaded in the list, as it shows the following figure:

[image: Temporal]

But I'm not getting the expected result, but add the product to my list ... it is necessary to refresh the page to view it through user interface.

the modal form button has an id = "btnSubmit" that calls the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                var myformdata = $("#myForm").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Ordens/AgregarDesayuno",
                    data: myformdata,
                    success: function () {
                        $("#myDesayuno").modal("hide");
                    }
                })
            })
        })
</script>
```

and my ActionResult in mi controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AgregarDesayuno(AddProducto addproducto)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {               
                var cantidad = addproducto.d_Cantidad;
                var ordentmp = db.OrdenDetalleTmps.Where(o => o.UserName == User.Identity.Name && o.Kn_CodigoProducto == addproducto.Kn_CodigoProducto).FirstOrDefault();
                if (ordentmp == null)
                {
                    var buscaproducto = db.Productoes.Find(addproducto.Kn_CodigoProducto);
                    var temporal = new OrdenDetalleTmp
                    {
                        v_Nombre = buscaproducto.v_Nombre,
                        Precio_Unitario = Convert.ToInt16(buscaproducto.Precio_Unitario),
                        d_Cantidad = Convert.ToInt16(addproducto.d_Cantidad),
                        UserName = User.Identity.Name,
                        Kn_CodigoProducto = buscaproducto.Kn_CodigoProducto,
                    };

                    db.OrdenDetalleTmps.Add(temporal);
                    db.SaveChanges();                  
                    return RedirectToAction("Create");
                }             
            }

            ViewBag.Kn_CodigoProducto = new SelectList(ComboHelper.GetDesayuno(), "Kn_CodigoProducto", "v_Nombre");
            return PartialView(addproducto);
        }
```

my GET method from the main view (open the list):

```
  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {         

            var view = new NewOrdenView()
            {
                f_Ingreso = DateTime.Now,
                ListaOrdenDetallesTmps = db.OrdenDetalleTmps.Where(edt => edt.UserName == User.Identity.Name).ToList(),
            };

            ViewBag.Kn_CodigoProducto = new SelectList(ComboHelper.GetDesayuno(), "Kn_CodigoProducto", "v_Nombre");            
            return View(view);
        }
```

How can I add a product to my list so that the user does not need to refresh the page to visualize it? I have very little knowledge of modal windows, any help for me?

coordinating greetings

Comment: What's the function you use to get the initial list? You just need to call that function again in the success call back, after you close the modal.

Comment: in my Get method of the action result I open my list this way:     var view = new NewOrdenView()
            {
                f_Ingreso = DateTime.Now,
                ListaOrdenDetallesTmps = db.OrdenDetalleTmps.Where(edt => edt.UserName == User.Identity.Name).ToList(),
            }; @Eliellel

Comment: Then you call the GET method again after POST to refresh the list.

Comment: what is the GET Method /controller action to fetch items?

Comment: and edited my question by writing the GET method that opens the list @user9405863

Comment: Where do I call the method that opens the list again? in the controller or in the script? I have updated my question @Eliellel

Comment: In the script, after `$("#myDesayuno").modal("hide");`

Comment: @fytoahse : try my answer .it should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading page from ajax success..it will load latest records in your list

try this one. hope this helps

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                var myformdata = $("#myForm").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Ordens/AgregarDesayuno",
                    data: myformdata,
                    success: function () {
                        window.location.reload(true);
                        $("#myDesayuno").modal("hide");
                    }
                })
            })
        })
</script>
```

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. To make a ajax call and refresh the page is crazy